# Did the Prophet Micaiah really see and hear the Lord and His host (1 Kgs. 22:20-21), and could any angel be a deceiving spirit (22:21)?

Tags: 1-kings, angels, spirits, dream

The prophet Micaiah related the Word of the Lord to kings Ahab and Jehoshaphat. Did he (Micaiah) really see the Lord and the host of heaven, or was this a vision?:

> **1 Kings 22:20-21**: Micaiah said, “Therefore, hear the word of the LORD. I saw the LORD sitting on His throne, and all the host of heaven standing by Him on His right and on His left. The LORD said, ‘Who will entice Ahab to go up and fall at Ramoth-gilead?’ And one said this while another said that. Then a spirit came forward and stood before the LORD and said, ‘I will entice him.’"

If the "spirit that came forward" was about to deceive Ahab, could it really have been an angel?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it wasn't an angel, for in the hebrew version we read the verse 21:

> וַיֵּצֵ֣א **הָר֗וּחַ** וַֽיַּעֲמֹד֙ לִפְנֵ֣י יְהֹוָ֔ה וַיֹּ֖אמֶר אֲנִ֣י
> אֲפַתֶּ֑נּוּ וַיֹּ֧אמֶר **יְהֹוָ֛ה** אֵלָ֖יו בַּמָּֽה׃

הָר֗וּחַ means *the spirit*, and in the following verse 22 it's called a *lying spirit*:

> וַיֹּ֗אמֶר אֵצֵא֙ וְהָיִ֙יתִי֙ **ר֣וּחַ שֶׁ֔קֶר** בְּפִ֖י כׇּל־נְבִיאָ֑יו
> וַיֹּ֗אמֶר תְּפַתֶּה֙ וְגַם־תּוּכָ֔ל צֵ֖א וַעֲשֵׂה־כֵֽן׃

Or in english:

> And he replied, ‘I will go out and be a **lying spirit** in the mouth of
> all his prophets.’ Then He said, ‘You will entice and you will
> prevail. Go out and do it.’

Concluding, it's all about a *spirit* in this case, there isn't a way to be thought as an angel, for angels are characteristics of G'd, **emanations**. Concerning the question if it was truly G'd (יְהֹוָ֛ה), the Lord, indeed, it was Him who was seen by the prophet.